# Get <ui:param> value of <ui:include> in managed bean

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, facelets, jsf-2.2, uiinclude

**index.xhtml**:

```
...
<ui:include src="#{part.fullPath}">
   <ui:param name="topListId" value="#{part.topListId}" rendered="#{part.topListNeeded}"/>
</ui:include>
...
```

`fullPath` is something like `"WEB-INF/parts/customPart.xhtml"`. It works well and each part is properly included and rendered. But the problem appears when I have the parameter to pass, i.e. when `part.topListNeeded==true`
One of the parts that I want to include has `fullPath=WEB-INF/parts/topList.xhtml, topListNeeded=true, topListId=1`.
**topList.xhtml**:

```
<h:body>        
   <f:metadata>
      <f:viewParam name="topListId" value="#{topListBean.topListId}" />
      <f:viewAction action="#{topListBean.init}" />
   </f:metadata>
   <ui:composition>
      <f:view>
         <ui:repeat value="#{topListBean.list}" var="row" rendered="#{!topListBean.listEmpty}">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.someData}"/>
         </ui:repeat>
      </f:view>
   </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

**topListBean.java**:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class TopListBean {
    private LinkedList<Event> list;
    private boolean listEmpty;
    private long topListId;

    public TopListEvents() {
        System.out.println("DEBUG ::: TopListEvents:constructor");
    }

    @PostConstruct // if I ommit this, init() is never called
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("DEBUG ::: TopListEvents:init");

        topListId = Long.parseLong(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
        getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().
        get("topListId")); // EXCEPTION: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null !!!

        // ...fetch toplist elements based on topListId...

        // ...getters and setters...
    }
```

I have the output:
`DEBUG ::: TopListEvents:constructor`
`DEBUG ::: TopListEvents:init`
...but then the exception is thrown (`java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`). I marked that place in the comments.
I will probably have multiple parts with parameters on my index page. The parameter will always be stored in `part.topListId`. What is the best way to pass those parameters?

Comment: What package is `@ViewScoped` from?

Comment: @Tiny, the package of the TopListBean class is toplist.beans, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Is it from `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`? (It should not mistakenly be imported from `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` (the managed bean will simply be treated as a request scoped bean in that case), since beans are managed by JSF (`@ManagedBean`) and not by the container itself -- CDI (`@Named`)).

Comment: Yes, it's javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped